# Плавное перемещение usercontrol по области Grid'a [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Поискал по сайту и ответа на мой вопрос я не нашел, поэтому решил создать новую тему. У меня есть полноэкранный Grid в котором находится usercontrol перемещаемый с помощью `TranslateTransform`. Все бы нечего если бы usercontrol успевал отрисовываться при перемещении... в итоге получается эффект как в старых ОС с тенью от мышки. Grid с WebControl идет четко за мышкой а позади рывками перемещается само окно...

Единственным выходом я вижу затормозить всего usercontrol'a до полной отрисовки. Так как делается в играх... Там окна перетаскиваются не точно за мышкой а с небольшим торможением. (Это не сильно затормозит перемещение но без него очень режет глаз отстающий рендер контола.)

Была идея занесение каждого тика перемещения в коллекцию из которой весь список будет обрабатываться так чтобы успевал все отрендерить. Или вообще переделать как-то способ перетаскивания окна...

привожу пример XAML разметки и событий по перемещению.

```
<UserControl x:Name="Browser" x:Class="ELUM.UI.Controls.ELUMBrowser"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:eo = "http://schemas.essentialobjects.com/wpf/"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ELUM.UI.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" Height="450">
    <UserControl.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="timer_tt"/>
    </UserControl.RenderTransform>
    <Grid x:Name="browser" Background="#FF18191D">
        <Grid x:Name="TopViev" Background="#FF3A4047" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonDown="Browser_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Browser_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Browser_MouseMove"/>
        <Grid Margin="3,50,3,3">
            <eo:WebControl x:Name="WebControl" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                <eo:WebControl.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="EOWebControl"/>
                </eo:WebControl.RenderTransform>
                <eo:WebControl.WebView >
                    <eo:WebView x:Name="WebView" Url = "vk.com" >
                    </eo:WebView >
                </eo:WebControl.WebView >
            </eo:WebControl >
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
        static Vector m_startOffset_timer;
        Point m_start;

        private void Browser_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            m_start = e.GetPosition((this.Parent as Grid));
            m_startOffset_timer = new Vector(timer_tt.X, timer_tt.Y);

            TopViev.CaptureMouse();
        }

        private void Browser_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TopViev.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        private void Browser_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TopViev.IsMouseCaptured)
            {
                Vector offset = Point.Subtract(e.GetPosition((this.Parent as Grid)), m_start);

                timer_tt.X = m_startOffset_timer.X + offset.X;
                timer_tt.Y = m_startOffset_timer.Y + offset.Y;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Ничего не понял

Comment: https://recordit.co/pG4qWqymsP   тут видео с примером как работает usercontrol.
Само содержимое перетаскивается без проблем а вот окно тормозит

Comment: Вопрос. зачем вы делаете расчет позиции контролла, который сам по себе будет закреплен в родителе, и будет двигаться за ним?

Comment: Я не делаю расчет позиции дочернего контрола.  Если вы про EOWebControl то это остался код после некоторых тестов. Да и сам контрол не перемещается при перетаскивании родителя. он перемещается только при изменении ширины или высоты родителя (очень странно). Странно то что именно контрол идет четко за мышкой без зависаний в отличии от его родительского элемента

Comment: Окей, что за поля `timer_tt`, `m_start`? Приведите ваш класс полностью, что бы можно было воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: Предоставьте [минимальный самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), пока вы говорите о каком то совершенно не понятном и не стандартном поведение WPF.

Comment: в XAML это все есть. 
`<TranslateTransform x:Name="timer_tt"/>`

а то что в классе я исправлю в самом вопросе

Comment: Собственно Я добавляю UserControl на Grid при загрузке приложения. в UserControl находится EOWebControl и дочерний Grid за который я делаю перетаскивание окна. Сам EOWebControl Адекватно перетаскивается не отставая за мышкой но вот сам UserControl который является родительским элементом для EOWebControl перетаскивается с подвисанием. (Если приложение запускать не через среду то это подвисание намного меньше но все же есть)

Comment: Мне не понятно как у вас вообще что то перемещается без `InvalidateMeasure()` and `InvalidateVisual()`

Comment: пару мин соберу отдельный проект с нужным кодом

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/nkNnr тут проект с полноэкранным окном и в нем доп окно которое перетаскивается. но перетаскивание таким образом подвисает очень сильно а не идет ровно за мышкой

Comment: @АртурФранк: Не воспроизводится. У вас видимо нет аппаратного ускорения отрисовки. И это никак не связано с WPF.